# Proof in complex

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, complex-numbers

Prove that for each $z\in \mathbb{C}$ we have $$\overline{\cos z} = \cos \overline{z}$$
using $ \cos z = {e^{iz}+e^{-iz}\over 2}$.

Can you please give me a link or show this proff using the equation i wrote. My english sucks so i can really search for it.

Comment: You ought to to try and learn the basic steps in such a question: First, you are asked to prove $X=Y$, so start with $X$, then use all the mathematical tools you have available to you to obtain "Y". Then you're done. They even tell you how to do it (use the exponent form of $\cos$). So the only thing remaining is for you to know what the "conjugate" is ($\bar{z}$). You should be able to use this approach to get from $X$ to $Y$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

\begin{eqnarray} \overline{\cos z} &=& \overline{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}\over 2}\\
&=& { \overline{e^{iz}}+\overline{e^{-iz}}\over 2}\\
&=& { e^{\overline{iz}}+{e^{\overline{-iz}}}\over 2}\\
&=& { e^{-i\overline{z}}+{e^{i\overline{z}}}\over 2}\\
&=& \cos{\overline{z}}
\end{eqnarray}

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $$\overline{e^z} = e^{\overline{z}}.$$